# Understanding Callback in Js function

Tags: javascript

Okay this is a basic question but as someone who has never worked with callback function before (ANYWHERE) and after many failures to understand what's going on, I thought that maybe you can help me.

Let's consider the following example:

When the html loads, the function `showtext` reveals the, passed as parameter, text by letter (just a tiny and beautiful animation). When this function finish, when all the sentence is shown, I want to call another function `showAuthor` that reveals the author of the above post.

```
function showText(target, message, index, interval, callback) {
    if (index < message.length) {
        $(target).append(message[index++]);
        setTimeout(function() { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
    }
    if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
        callback();
    }

}

function showAuthor() {
    var name = '<span>as posted by someone</span>';
    $(name).hide().appendTo(".author").fadeIn(300);
}

$(function() {
    showText("#aboutMeMsg", "Some VERY cool text here", 0, 100, showAuthor());
});
```

#### The problem

The problem with the above code is that the function `showAuthor` is executed the same time when the function `showtext` is starting. That means that the `showAuthor` is able to complete **before** `showText` is completed.

I think the problem is that I use the function `showText` is recursive, but I can't solve the problem.

Now why is this happening, I can't get it....

Comment: you try to pass the callback invoked hence in fact you are not passing the `showAuthor` function as a callback but it's return value as a parameter to the `showText` function. (probably as "undefined")

Comment: @Redu yes but I didn't get any errors on firebug console

Comment: you don't get any errors because there are no errors as per the vm is concerned. It's about semantics. You are passing the return value of the `showAuthor` function to `showText` function which is probably `"undefined"` and in the `showText` function you check the `callback` parameter with `if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {callback();}` and it just evaluates to false. You should pass `showAuthor` function's definition as indicated in the given answers. I mean without the invoking parens.

Comment: Be aware even once you get the callback working, it won't have the effect you describe, as it will be called after the first call to showText().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help

```
    function showText(target, message, index, interval, callback) {
      if (index < message.length) {
        $(target).append(message[index++]);
        setTimeout(function() { showText(target, message, index, interval, callback); }, interval);
      } else if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
        callback();
      }
    }

    function showAuthor() {
      var name = '<span>as posted by someone</span>';
      $(name).hide().appendTo(".author").fadeIn(300);
    }

    $(function() {
      showText("#aboutMeMsg", "Some VERY cool text here", 0, 100, showAuthor);
    });
```

You actually need to pass a callback function reference `showAuthor` in the `showText` function, rather than the invoking it `showAuthor()`.

Comment: yes you are right about the `else` statement. I hate logical faults. You just have to add the callback parameter also in the recursively invoking `showText` function. Edit it and I'll accept you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the showAuthor without the brackets. Because using the brackets means you are invoking that function. Something like below:

```
$(function() {
    showText("#aboutMeMsg", "Some VERY cool text here", 0, 100, showAuthor);
});
```

And then you need to pass the same `callback` when you are recursively invoking the `showText` function

Edit:

```
setTimeout(function() { showText(target, message, index, interval, callback); }, interval);
```

Comment: can you explain using my example what the `invoking that function` means? It didn't worked as expected

Comment: @GeorgeGkas `setTimeout(function() { showText(target, message, index, interval, callback); }, interval);`

Answer (score 0):

First you should correct the callback passing as indicated in the previous answers. So it should be like ;

```
$(function() {
    showText("#aboutMeMsg", "Some VERY cool text here", 0, 100, showAuthor);
});
```

Yet, in the `showText` function when you make a call to your callback it executes synchronously and this is the problem. You should send your callback to the end of the event queue so that it runs after the `showText` function. You may try changing the following line

```
if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
  callback();
}
```

to

```
if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
  setTimeout(callback,0);
}
```